# is it possible to compare 2 Excel columns, 1 date type and 1 column that contains a formula but 'displays' a date?

Tags: excel, vlookup, formulas, date-comparison

I have a workbook with two sheets:

Sheet 1 holds case information, names 'Cases'
   In Cases, column A holds Names and column B shows dates

Sheet 2 holds additional user information and is named 'Click'
   In Click, column A is `CreatedDate`, column C is `Name`, G is `Date` and column H is `Date` (different from column A).

I have a formula populating column G in Click that references the Cases tab:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,[List]Cases!A:C,2,FALSE),"No")`

The above is working like a champ. It is looking up the user name in Cases, and comparing to the Name in Click. If it finds a match, it populates the Date in the click tab column G.

**My Question(s):**

I am getting some extra matches. This is due to `VLOOKUP` only finding the first instance I think. I have this example:

[screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrGBq.jpg)

**Problem 1:**
In the above example, Column G shows 3/27/2017 in all 4 rows. It should really only show when there is a direct match, so the two rows for 3/31/2017 are wrong. Not sure if there is a way around this using something other than VLOOKUP?

**Problem 2:**
If the above is not something I can work around, I figures I could add a condition in a count column saying that columns A and G must match in order to be counted as a '1' in column H. The issue there is that the date in column G is the result of the lookup formula, and it breaks this attempt at comparison:

`=IF((A3=G3),1,0)`

I get nothing but 0's, so it isn't seeing the VLOOKUP column as an actual date.

Sorry this is so long - hope it's not like reading 'War and Peace'.  I am kind of new to these complex formulas and have a lot to learn. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `=IF((A3=G3),1,0)`, just type `=A3=G3`.  It does the same thing.

Comment: Also, in your screenshot, I don't see row numbers.  Which cell is A3 and which is G3?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful for you to convert your values to text to see what's going on.  Use this formula to convert a date to text `=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")`.  FYI, to convert text back to dates, use `=DATEVALUE(A1)`

Comment: you can use an array formula `=MIN(($A$1:$A$100="sue")*($B$1:$B$100="01/01/2001")*(ROW($A$1:$A$100))` for example to give the row then `INDEX` from that.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions...I think Nathan_Sav answered the question and it looks like he has the solution. Now I just need to figure out his formula!

Answer (score 0):

Ive data in one sheet, for ease, but using the following array

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MAX(--($A$2:$A$7=F2)*--($B$2:$B$7=G2)*(ROW($A$2:$A$7)))-1,1)
```

I think I get what you require.

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want, but sorry to say I don't understand the array formula. My data is in two sheets called Clicks and Cases. The formula is in the sheet called Clicks, looking up in the sheet called Cases. Not sure how to specify in the above when it should go looking in another sheet?  Thank you for this - it looks perfect!

Comment: What sheet is "Person" and "Value" in and which is the "Person" and "Date Value"

Comment: OK, I have tried a load of things with the above, but everything I do results in the old favorite #VALUE!. I guess I really don't understand array formulas at all.

Comment: I have Person in both sheets, CLICKS and CASES. I am using it as a match. The Date is also in both sheets - in some cases. One sheet shows web site behavior, and the other shows cases opened. I am trying to establish which users who engaged in sessions on a web site went on to open support cases. If they did, I want to see the date from the CASES sheet populate in the CLICKS sheet.   It is possible that part of my problems come from inconsistent date fields. Converting them doesn't help though.